# How to make list in jQuery mobile nested list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

Can you please tell me how to make list in jQuery mobile? I am trying to make this type list as given in fiddle on pop up screen dynamically .

Here is the [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hFHg9/85/)

In this fiddle I make two rows.In first row there is only p tag. But in second row there is nested collapsible rows. I need to make same thing in pop up screen. I am able to make first row. But In my second row contend is null why? Can you suggest where I am wrong?

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Jw98p/)

```
 $(function () {

        $('#test').click(function(){
            alert('d');
            createCommandPopUpTabs();
            $("#tabbedPopup").popup("open");


        });
    });
    var tabsHeader = [ "InputParameter", "basic"];
    var tabsHeader_basic = [  "XYZ", "Third Level",
         ];

    function createCommandPopUpTabs(){
        var header = "<h3 >dd</h3>";
        var commmand = 'dd';
        var button = '<button onclick="return submitCommand(&quot;'+
                '&quot;)" style="" class="donebtn common-button1">Save</button>';
        $("#commandInfo").append(button);

        $("#commandInfoheader").html(header);
        for ( var i = 0; i < tabsHeader.length; i++) {
            var headerId = tabsHeader[i] + "_tab" + commmand;
            var header = "<div data-role='collapsible' data-collapsed='false' id='"
                    + headerId + "'><h3>InputParameter</h3></div>";
            var content ;
            if(tabsHeader[i]=="InputParameter"){
                content = "<p>yes</p>";
            }else  if(tabsHeader[i]=="basic"){
                for ( var i = 0; i < tabsHeader_basic.length; i++) {
                    headerId = tabsHeader_basic[i] + "_tab" + commmand;
                    header = "<div data-role='collapsible' data-collapsed='false' id='"
                            + headerId + "'><h3>basic</h3></div>";
                    content += getcontend(tabsHeader_basic[i]);



                }
            }

            $("#tabbedSet").append(header);
            $("#tabbedSet").find("#" + headerId).append(content);
            $("#tabbedSet").collapsibleset("refresh");

        }
    }

        function getcontend(name){
            if(name=="Third Level"){
                return"<p>Third Level></p>";
            } if(name=="XYZ"){
                return"<p> second Level></p>";
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are errors in your code and logic. I will only go over a couple of them to hopefully get you on the right path:

In `tabsHeader_basic` array the `Third Level` has a space in it which you later use as an ID which makes it an invalid ID because you cannot have spaces in an ID.

[From the HTML 5 Draft:](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute)
**`The value must not contain any space characters.`**

Also, the "basic" collapsible div needs to exist before you start adding the nested collapsible div.
So this line needs to come out of the for loop
`header = "<div data-role='collapsible' data-collapsed='false' id='"+ headerId + "'><h3>basic</h3></div>";`

Go through the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/56cSb/) and compare your code agaisnt my changes.

Hopefully that helps! Let me know if you have any other questions.

Comment: great answer can you please tell why all row display with expand ?

Comment: mean "xyz", third lvel and basic all rows are expanded..!!

Comment: It's because of the `data-collapsed='false'` property on the divs. change them to `data-collapsed='true'`

Answer (score 1):

I have updated `createCommandPopUpTabs()` function.

Also removed space in `Third Level` on `var tabsHeader_basic = ["XYZ", "ThirdLevel"];`
Check the [**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Jw98p/8/)

```
function createCommandPopUpTabs() {
    var header = "<h3 >dd</h3>";
    var commmand = 'dd';
    var button = '<button onclick="return submitCommand(&quot;' +
            '&quot;)" style="" class="donebtn common-button1">Save</button>';
    $("#commandInfo").html(button);

    $("#commandInfoheader").html(header);
    $("#tabbedSet").html('');
    for (var i = 0; i < tabsHeader.length; i++) {
        var headerId = tabsHeader[i] + "_tab" + commmand;
        var header = "<div data-role='collapsible' data-collapsed='true' id='" + headerId + "'><h3>" + tabsHeader[i] + "</h3></div>";
        $("#tabbedSet").append(header);
        var content;
        if (tabsHeader[i] == "InputParameter") {
            content = "<p>yes</p>";
            $("#tabbedSet").find("#" + headerId).append(content);
        } else if (tabsHeader[i] == "basic") {
            for (var j = 0; j < tabsHeader_basic.length; j++) {
                var headerId1 = tabsHeader_basic[j] + "_tab" + commmand;
                var header1 = "<div data-role='collapsible' data-collapsed='true' id='" + headerId1 + "'><h3>" + tabsHeader_basic[j] + "</h3></div>";
                var content1 = getcontend(tabsHeader_basic[j]);
                $("#tabbedSet").find("#" + headerId).append(header1);
                $("#tabbedSet").find("#" + headerId1).append(content1);
            }
        }
        $("#tabbedSet").collapsibleset("refresh");
    }
}
```